# Size and offset are optional in the URL - Spider(crawling) Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I practice pulling data from the internet, from the website: https://finance.yahoo.com/crypto

I'm trying to pull data from the table (for example the entire Symbol column). This works for the first page, I'm now trying to figure out how to get all the data from the following pages, according to the url I see that there are optional fields (count=25&offset=50) for interest.
If you try to move between the pages you will see it for real.

The part I don't understand how to implement it in the code.
Here is the written code:

```
import json
import os

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv



class CrawlingYahoo(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mycrawler4"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://finance.yahoo.com"]
    items_set = set()  # Use a set to store unique symbols
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/crypto(\?count=\d+&offset=\d+)?$"), callback="parse_item"),
        # Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="crypto"), callback="parse_item"),
    )




    def parse_item(self,response):
        rows = response.xpath('//*[@id="scr-res-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr')
        for row in rows:
            symbol = row.xpath('.//td[1]/a/text()').get()
            if symbol not in self.items_set:  # Check if symbol already exists in the set
                item = {
                    "Symbol": symbol,
                    "Name": row.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").get(),
                    "Price": row.xpath(".//td[3]/fin-streamer/text()").get()
                }
                self.items_set.add(symbol)  # Add symbol to the set
                yield item
        print(self.items_set)

    # def closed(self,response):
    #
    #     with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    #         json.dump(self.items_list, f)
        # self.collection.insert_many(self.items_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(CrawlingYahoo)
    process.start()
```

I need to add rules i think but i don't know if its right. Please let me know if you need something

[After press next in the table i need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Rsl.png)

Comment: Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question. Please do not include images in your question, but rather a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).